# Django Rest Framework Am I doing it right?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have studied DRF myself and one question bothers me, unfortunately I have no one to ask and this question bothers me all the time. Is writing application logic in views (as in the attached code) a good approach? When sending a query to the server with the intention, for example, to accept an order, I have to update the values ​​from models other than the order or carry out validation of statuses, change the data on their basis. In the first tutorials from which I learned, among others, [JustDjango](https://github.com/justdjango/django-react-ecommerce/tree/master/core/api) all logic is in the view. However, after writing some code and watching other tutorials, I feel that this is not the right approach. Should not save and update models be done through a serializer? If so, whether through one large serializer or several smaller serializers.

```
class ZK_AddUpdateItemWithInstaReservation(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pzitem_id = request.data.get('pzitem_id')
    ordered_quantity  = request.data.get('ordered_quantity')
    order_id = request.data.get('order_id')
    user_id = request.data.get('user_id')
    item_id = request.data.get('item_id')

    if ordered_quantity:
        if int(ordered_quantity) < 0:
            return Response({'error': 'Próbujesz zamówić ujemną wartość'})
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    except:
        return Response({'error': 'Item with given id does not exists'})
    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    except:
        return Response({'error': 'Order with given id does not exist'})
    if order.status not in ['SD', 'WTZ']:
        return Response({'message': 'Nie można zmieniać ilości na zamówionym zamówieniu lub w realizacji'})
    order.status = 'WTZ'
    order.save()
    # ORDERED ITEM WITHOUT PZITEM ON STOCK
    if not pzitem_id:
        # CHECK IF ORDER CONTAINS ORDERITEM
        try:
            orderitem = OrderItem.objects.get(pzitem=None, order=order, item=item)
            prev_ordered_quantity = orderitem.quantity
            # UPDATE ORDER ITEM VALUES
            orderitem.quantity = ordered_quantity
            orderitem.quantity_do_wydania = ordered_quantity
            orderitem.status = 'ZBR'
            orderitem.save()
            # UPDATE ITEM VALUES
            item = Item.objects.get(id=orderitem.item_id)
            prev_item_not_ordered_plus_qty_prevordered = item.quantity_not_ordered + prev_ordered_quantity
            item.quantity_not_ordered = int(prev_item_not_ordered_plus_qty_prevordered) - int(ordered_quantity)
            item.save()
            return Response({'message': 'Zaktualizowano ilość przedmiotu bez rezerwacji stanu'})
        except:
            # IF NOT CREATE ONE
            orderitem = OrderItem.objects.create(user_id=user_id, pzitem=None, item=item, quantity=ordered_quantity, quantity_do_wydania=ordered_quantity, status='ZBR', order=order)
            orderitem.save()
            # UPDATE ITEM VALUES
            item = Item.objects.get(id=orderitem.item_id)
            item.quantity_not_ordered -= int(ordered_quantity)
            item.save()
            return Response({'messsage': 'Dodano nowy przedmiot do zamowienia, status bez rezerwacji stanu.'})
    # ORDERED WITH STOCK
    else:
        try:
            pzitem = PZItem.objects.get(id=pzitem_id)
        except:
            return Response({'error': 'Nie znaleziono pzitem z podanym pzitem_id'})
        # CHECK IF ORDER CONTAINS ORDERITEM
        try:
            orderitem = OrderItem.objects.get(pzitem=pzitem, order=order, item=item)
            prev_ordered_quantity = orderitem.quantity
            if int(ordered_quantity) <= prev_ordered_quantity + orderitem.pzitem.quantity_available_to_order:
                prev_ordered_quantity = orderitem.quantity
                # UPDATE ORDER ITEM VALUES
                orderitem.status = 'ZZR'
                orderitem.quantity = ordered_quantity
                orderitem.quantity_do_wydania = ordered_quantity
                orderitem.save()
            
                # UPDATE ITEM VALUES
                item = Item.objects.get(id=orderitem.item_id)
                prev_item_not_ordered_plus_qty_prevordered = item.quantity_not_ordered + prev_ordered_quantity
                item.quantity_not_ordered = int(prev_item_not_ordered_plus_qty_prevordered) - int(ordered_quantity)
                item.save()
                # UPDATE PZITEM VALUES
                prev_pzitem_quantity_ordered = int(orderitem.pzitem.quantity_ordered)
                orderitem.pzitem.quantity_ordered =  int(orderitem.pzitem.quantity_ordered) - int(prev_ordered_quantity) + int(ordered_quantity)
                orderitem.pzitem.save()
                return Response({'message': 'Zaktualizowano ilość przedmiotu z rezerwacją stanu'})
            else:
                return Response({'warning': 'Zamówiono więcej niż dostępne'})
        except:
            # IF NOT CREATE ONE
            if int(ordered_quantity) or 0 <= pzitem.quantity_available_to_order:
                orderitem = OrderItem.objects.create(user_id=user_id, pzitem=pzitem, item=item, quantity=ordered_quantity, quantity_do_wydania=ordered_quantity, status='ZZR', order=order)
                orderitem.save()
                # UPDATE ITEM VALUES
                item = Item.objects.get(id=orderitem.item_id)
                item.quantity_not_ordered -= int(ordered_quantity)
                item.save()
                # UPDATE PZITEM VALUES
                orderitem.pzitem.quantity_ordered += int(ordered_quantity)
                orderitem.pzitem.save()
                return Response({'messsage': 'Dodano nowy przedmiot do zamowienia, status zamówiono z rezerwacją stanu.'})
            else:
                return Response({'warning': 'Zamówiono więcej niż dostępne'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have so much logic in views.py its not a best way. Separate your model actions to other views and serializer. For example for your order operations you can implement view and serializers like this.

```
class UpdateOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pzitem_id = serializers.CharField()
    ordered_quantity = serializers.IntegerField()
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(User.objects.all())
    item = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(OrderItem.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if attrs["ordered_quantity"] < 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(dict(ordered_quantity="Próbujesz zamówić ujemną wartość"))

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.status = "WTZ"
        # do some other things
        instance.save()
        return instance

class ZK_AddUpdateItemWithInstaReservation(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    queryset = Order.objects.all()

    @action(detail=True)
    def update_order(self, request, pk):
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK, data={})
```

If you have so much operations which is related between them. You can create a pipelines. Like this;

```
class YourPipeline:
    def __init__(self, past_some_data):
        self.past_some_data = past_some_data
        
    def update_order_status(self):
        # update your order
        
    def create_order_item(self):
        # do something else    
    
    def some_function(self):
        # another operation
    
    def run(self):
        self.update_order_status()
        self.create_order_item()
        self.some_function()
        return instance


class UpdateOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pzitem_id = serializers.CharField()
    ordered_quantity = serializers.IntegerField()
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(User.objects.all())
    item = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(OrderItem.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if attrs["ordered_quantity"] < 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(dict(ordered_quantity="Próbujesz zamówić ujemną wartość"))

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pipeline = YourPipeline(past_some_data=past_some_data)
        return pipeline.run()
        

class ZK_AddUpdateItemWithInstaReservation(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    queryset = Order.objects.all()

    @action(detail=True)
    def update_order(self, request, pk):
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are a few things wrong with the code in your case:

1. As you wrote, saving the data should be done through the serializer.
   In my opinion, it should be one serializer that will write data in one transaction.
2. In case of errors you should not return status code 200, just one of the 4XX errors
3. If you want to reduce or enlarge the model field:

```
item.quantity_not_ordered -= int(ordered_quantity)
```

u should use
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f

4. You shouldn't use

```
try:
  foo()
except:
  pass
```

It is good practice to explicitly catch any exceptions that may occur